# convertirAtexto en pseint

Tags: java, python, pseint

muy buena soy estudiante novato de la universidad y el profesor nos puso un ejercicio ende PSeint y no supe como hacerlo y chat gpt me ayudó pero no entiendo la parte que sale convertir texto y quiero saber que hizo allí.

el ingeniero nos dio los siguientes datos para que lo mostráramos en pantalla

Y   8       1
Y   7       2
Y   6       3
Y   5       1
Y   4       2
X   3       3
X   2       1
X   1       2
X   0       3
X   -1      1

ESTE ES EL CODIGO QUE ME MUESTRA CORRECTAMENTE LO QUE EL PIDE PERO QUIERO COMPRENDER LA PARTE DEL SI ENTONCES

```
Algoritmo sin_titulo
i <- 8
j <- 1
Para i<-8 Hasta -2 Hacer
    Si i>3 Entonces
        Escribir 'Y   '+ConvertirAtexto(i)+'   '+ConvertirAtexto(j) 
    SiNo
        Escribir 'X   '+ConvertirAtexto(i)+'   '+ConvertirAtexto(j)
    FinSi
    j <- (j MOD 3)+1
FinPara
```

FinAlgoritmo

Comment: supongo que te refieres a concatenar

Comment: Hola The RamGui, bienvenido, la sentencia "si-entonces" la puedes leer como "mientras se cumpla esta condición, se ejecuta el código que tengo adentro", osea, si **i** es mayor que **3**, "Ecribir "Y" + blabla".., cuando **i** no sea mayor que **3**, entrará en **SINO** y ejecutará su contenido.